# Why does adding .toISOString() to my timestamp alter the timezone?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp

I need to insert data into my collection with a timestamp reflecting MY timezone, as demonstrated in the code below.

```
console.log("Testing time: " +new Date(new Date().getTime()+(-7*24*60*60*1000)) )
```

The code above yields: `Testing time: Sat May 29 2021 14:59:14 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)` ...correctly indicating my current timezone!

In order to be able to query my collection based on the various times, I need to format the timestamp by appending `.toISOString()` to the `new Date()` function as demonstrated in the code below:

```
console.log("Testing time: " +new Date(new Date().getTime()+(-7*24*60*60*1000)).toISOString() )
```

The code above yields: `Testing time: 2021-05-29T11:59:08.662Z` However **NOTE** that by appending `.toISOString()`, the timezone changes.

How do use this format, and STILL maintain my timezone?

Comment: The timezone isn't changing, it's just displaying it in ISO format, which includes the `Z` indicating UTC.

Comment: You can get ISO format in your required timezone using *toLocaleString* with `new Date('Sat May 29 2021 14:59:14 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)').toLocaleString('sv',{timeZone:'Africa/Nairobi',timeZoneName:'short'})`, however I think [formatting it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49332027/257182) (a library can help but isn't required) is a far better approach.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does adding .toISOString() to my timestamp alter the timezone?

It doesn't, it just produces a string in UTC. It does that because that's how `toISOString` is [specifically defined](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring).

JavaScript's `Date` object holds the date/time as milliseconds since The Epoch (midnight on January 1st 1970 UTC). It's just that some methods (like `toString` or `getFullYear`) interpret that number by applying your local timezone offset, while other methods (like `toISOString` or `getUTCFullYear`) stick with UTC.

> How do use this format, and STILL maintain my timezone?

By formatting it yourself via `getHours`, `getDate`, `getTimezoneOffset`, `String.prototype.padStart`, etc. There's no built-in `Date` method that produces that format in the local timezone.

For example, the date part of it would be:

```
`${String(dt.getFullYear)}-${String(dt.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0")}-${String(dt.getDate()).padStart(2, "0")}`
```

`getTimezoneOffset` gives you the timezone offset from local time to UTC as total minutes (`-180` in your case), so you'd divide and remainder it to get the hours and minutes for the `GMT+0300` string (that `0300` is `HHMM`).