# Minus one hour from now and convert to ISODate?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to minus one hour from now and try to convert it to IsoString.

```js
let date = new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60
// Here I am trying to get past hour time by minus 1 hour.

console.log(date.toISOString())
// Here I am getting one error like
// date.toISOString is not a function
```

Why I am getting this error - `date.toISOString is not a function`. Please help me.

Comment: Because `getTime()` does not return a datetimeobject, but a int. You'll need something like `date.setHours(date.getHours() - 1);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying an ISO Date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684603/modifying-an-iso-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Try using `setTime` instead for example `date.setTime(date.getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60)`

Comment: Still getting same error.

Answer (score 3):

```
var date = new Date()

date.setHours(date.getHours() - 1);

console.log(date.toISOString())
```

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Same error I say in my questions

Comment: I don't get any error when it is runing. Can you show it?